# Cannot build Maven project in codename one build server (Error Log)

Tags: codenameone

Using Netbeans 11.3. Create the project from https://start.codenameone.com/. copy the contents of the tools/netbeans directory into the root project directory. I can run the project simulator, run the project simulator in debug mode fine. When I build the project to send to the CN1 build server it fails and I get a long Error Log. The first lines of the log are: -

```
Found hyp.beamId
Tried to start hyperlog but failed: Failed to start hyperlog: Cannot run program "hyp": 
error=2, No such file or directory
User-level: 9000
Request Args: 
-----------------
hyp.beamId=98214081-18fb-4b78-963b-b4bd363fe576
java.version=8
maven.codenameone-maven-plugin=7.0.58
ios.newStorageLocation=true
maven.codenameone-core.version=LATEST
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/seldwwr75ex3wpa/error%20%2810%29.txt?dl=0

Comment: That's odd. Do you have any extra dependencies in the project?

Comment: I commented out all my code (leaving imports), sent to cn1 build server, it worked. I added it back bit by bit. It failed with one particular line of code where I get string length(). I again removed this and it worked again. Not long after I then got another error stating designer_1.jar file was corrupt. I also seem to have another issue with Netbeans. Seems that the simulator does not always close properly, the next time I try to run it just hangs on starting... or some error appears. I then need to restart netbeans for this to run again. Tryin IntelliJ. If persists I will make a test case

Comment: Which project template did you use from the Codename One initializr?  Did you modify app before building it, or did you send unchanged to build server?  Which OS are you using, and what version of JDK are you using with the project?

Comment: I used the Bare-bones Java App. I built it first then modified after. Previous attempts to convert ANT project to Maven failed with the same type error log. I then tried to copy the code to a new project which is where I did the above tests adding code back bit by bit. Currently using Netbeans 11.3 on windows 10 machine with Java SE Developement Kit 8 Update 311. Since all of the above, I have begun to use IntelliJ and everything is working as expected. New projects and converted ones with the same project code etc.

Comment: Further information, maven migration tool version used was 1.0.3 with "LATEST" selected for codename one plugin version used.

Comment: The barebones build works. Right?
Did you set the correct package name when you created the barebones project? Where in these stages did it stop working, what was the change?

Comment: Yes bare-bones worked at first. I will try and make a test case to simplify.